# Refrigerator restarts when a 3 pin plug is plugged to socket like Laptop Adaptor

Tags: grounding, refrigerator, neutral

Over last few months I'm noticing whenever I connect my Laptop cord and turn on the switch my Refrigerator in the kitchen is restarts as if power has gone and comeback.

This happens primarily with 3 pin plugs.

If I turn on the UPS of my desktop computer Refrigerator restarts in the kitchen. The same happens when I plug in Laptop cord and turn on the switch (not every time but when the charges is not connected for a long time).

I got an electrician for checking but everything seems to be fine with the wiring. While trying to switch the device we measured the voltage and there isn't any fluctuations.

Is there any idea on what could be going on here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you have the fridge door open when you plug in the laptop, does the fridge light flash? Is anything going wrong other than the apparent coincidence? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Yes, we need to know more about your electrical wiring. Do you own a voltmeter?

Comment: I've multimeter at home; I measured the voltage variations if any when I plug in laptop cord or turn on my Computer UPS. But I didn't find voltages variations. Even if I keep the fridge door open the light flashes and it restarts, no difference in behaviour. I didn't notice any other devices behaving erratically. But few days ago one of socket burnt of in the neutral line when one appliances were connected to it.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: There is country by name India there I'm